# EXT-js PropertyGrid best practices to achieve an update?

Tags: ajax, extjs, propertygrid

I am using EXT-js for a project, *usually* everything is pretty straight forward with EXT-js, but with the propertyGrid, I am not sure.
I'd like some advice about this piece of code.

First the store to populate the property grid, 
on the load event:

```
 var configStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        // store config
     autoLoad:true,
        url: url.remote,
        baseParams : {xaction : 'read'},
        storeId: 'configStore',
        // reader config
        idProperty: 'id_config',
        root: 'config',
     totalProperty: 'totalcount',
        fields: [{
            name: 'id_config'
        }, {
            name: 'email_admin'
        }
  , {
            name: 'default_from_addr'
        }
  , {
            name: 'default_from_name'
        }
  , {
            name: 'default_smtp'
        }
  ],listeners: {
            load: {
                fn: function(store, records, options){
                    // get the property grid component
                    var propGrid = Ext.getCmp('propGrid');
                    // make sure the property grid exists
                    if (propGrid) {
                        // populate the property grid with store data
                        propGrid.setSource(store.getAt(0).data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

here is the propertyGrid:

```
 var propsGrid = new Ext.grid.PropertyGrid({
        renderTo: 'prop-grid',
     id: 'propGrid',
        width: 462,
        autoHeight: true,
        propertyNames: {
            tested: 'QA',
            borderWidth: 'Border Width'
        },
        viewConfig : {
            forceFit: true,
            scrollOffset: 2 // the grid will never have scrollbars
        }
    });
```

So far so good, but with the next button, I'll trigger an old school update,
and my question :

Is that the proper way to update this component ?
Or is it better to user an editor ?
or something else...

for regular grid I use the store methods to do the update, delete,etc...

The examples are really scarce on this one! 
Even in books about ext-js!

```
 new Ext.Button({
        renderTo: 'button-container',
        text: 'Update',
        handler: function(){

    var grid = Ext.getCmp("propGrid");  

                     var source = grid.getSource();  

                     var jsonDataStr = null;  

                     jsonDataStr = Ext.encode(source);  

     var requestCg = {  
                             url : url.update,  
                             method : 'post',  
                             params : {  
                                 config : jsonDataStr , xaction : 'update'
                             },  
                             timeout : 120000,  
                             callback : function(options, success, response) {  
                                 alert(success + "\t" + response);  
    }
   };
    Ext.Ajax.request(requestCg);   
        }
    });
```

and thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be fine.  The PropertyGrid and supporting classes were included early on in Ext, even before a lot of the classes in the current Ext.data.* namespace.  It never really got fully updated to match the APIs available on the other standard data classes.  The PropertyGrid actually does use a plain Ext.data.Store under the hood to store its data, but the typical store methods and events are not exposed.  As such, you'll either have to make do with `getSource()` or else start doing some major overriding.